# Regex to trim leading zeros from IPv4 octets

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex in a PHP script to collect IPv4 Addresses and to also perform some validation of the IPv4 addresses.

A txt file of IPs is read into an array with a `file()` command, then a foreach loop using `preg_match` and this regex matches the IPv4 addresses.

However, it currently includes any leading zeros before each octet.

Is it possible to improve this regex to **trim** any leading zeros in each octet without completely discarding IPs with leading zeros? I would prefer to do this in a single regex instead of adding an additional function to clear the leading zeros.

```
/(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/
```

Correct output:

```
38.10.125.242
38.1.1.24
```

Incorrect output:

```
038.010.125.242
038.001.001.024
```

I have been using [Lumadis.be](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php) to test, but none of the regexes that I tried from other answers in Stack Overflow seem to work?.

Comment: I don't see why you don't want those leading zero's. Also incorrect according to what?

Comment: It is used in a FreeBSD pf Table which faults on leading zeros.

Comment: You can't "remove" the leading zero's without actually applying some logical functions to it. [**Here**](https://eval.in/232310)'s something fancy that requires php 5.3+. On another note: I won't use `preg_match()` in a loop due to performance issues. You might take a look at `preg_grep()` or just use the method I have shown before...

Comment: You can simply `preg_replace('/\.0+/', '.')`

Comment: @HamZa  This seems to remove single zero octets also. ie 38.10.0.0 would output to 38.10..   Would you have a `preg_replace()` regex that might work. All the ones listed here don't work in this scenario or in your attached code.

Comment: @CA171 It seems that someone came with a solution. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler is just:

```
preg_replace('/\b0+/', '', $str);
```

Since we know the only word boundaries are at the . and the start/end of line

**Edit:** it looks like we need a lookahead to avoid empty octets

```
preg_replace('/\b0+(?=\d)/', '', $str)
```

Comment: This seems to remove single zero octets also. ie 38.10.0.0 would output to 38.10..

Comment: Sorry did you post a new edit? It seems to be the same? All of the other answers have the same effect (removing single zero octets)

Comment: Bingo! That seems to work. I will confirm if I find any exceptions.. Thanks @pguardiario

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `filter_var` and a simple transformation expression:

```
// strip leading zeroes from each octet
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\.)0+(?=\d)/', '', $str);

if (filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) !== false) {
  // valid ipv4 address
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for these example "038.010.000.000", "008.010.0.0"   outputs to  38.10.00.00, 08.10.0.0. Still some leading zeros remain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ips = preg_replace('/(^|\D)00?/i', '$1', $ips);
```

This Regex assumes that the ip is always in ### example: 000.000.000.000 format

Test it here:
https://regex101.com/r/3kFwu0/1

Shorter version: [(source)](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/15491-regex-to-strip-leading-zeroes-out-of-an-ip-address-octet/)

```
 $ips = preg_replace('\b0+\B', '', $ips);
```